# Retrieve EXIF data from gallery image in onActivityResult

Tags: android, image, geolocation, exif

Currently I am getting an image back from the gallery and populating an imageField with it. I am attempting to pull location information from the image, assuming it exists, but all I keep getting is null values.

I know the image I am testing with has entries for latitude and longitude in its EXIF data.

I've tried everything I can find online and nothing is working. I believe the problem lies in the improper parameter being sent to the ExifInterface. Here's what I've got right now:

```
...

else if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY) {
        try {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String currentImage = selectedImage.getPath()
            + File.separator + getFileName(selectedImage);
....
```

Then initialize the ExifInterface:

```
....

try {
    ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(currentImage);
    imageLatitude = ei.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE);
    imageLongitude = ei.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE);
....
```

But imageLatitude and imageLongitude are returning null. I've even gone so far as to replace the parameter sent into ExifInterface as the full path to the image (`/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150119_170010.jpg`) but still getting null values.

What exactly is supposed to be passed into ExifInterface and, if I'm passing in the correct parameter, why am I getting null values?

Comment: Is there any exceptions in the logcat?

Comment: I don't get any errors except an NPE when I try to log the value of the latitude without checking that it's not null. Which it always is. I do get some line that says "can't open path/being/sent/into/ExifInterface"

Answer (score 2):

I ended up getting it to work using this method:

```
private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI, Activity activity) {
    Cursor cursor = activity.getContentResolver()
                    .query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file
        // path
        return contentURI.getPath();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        return cursor.getString(idx);
    }
}
```

See it in use here:

```
if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY) {
        try {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String currentImageFile = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage, this);

            ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(currentImageFile);
```

This provided a proper ExifInterface that allowed me to pull the desired data from the image (where it existed).

Thanks for the input everyone.

Comment: I got the same issue. But "MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA" is not found in cursor. Just have following columns: _display_name, _size, mime_type, orientation, datetaken, latitude, longitude. Do you know why? Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me in Xamarin.Android. I was facing this exif issue only in OEM specific gallery app and in google photo app it was working. taking the original path loooks like working for both

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the image path you passed to ExifInterface is invalid, you can check it by using the code:

```
File file = new File(currentImage); 
if(file.exists()){ 
// print file exist
}else{
 // print file not exist.
}
```

If it's the problem, you can solve it by pass a valid image path. If it's not the problem you can debug your code and see the attributes in the `ExifInterface ei` object by adding a breakpoint before the following code:

imageLatitude = ei.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE);

Comment: I gave this a go and I'm not getting a File apparently. I was pretty sure this was the case. Now it's a matter of getting a File from the returned Uri. Any suggestions?